# Angular compiler fails with jsonwebtoken

Tags: angular, jwt, frontend, single-page-application

So, when i try to add jsonwebtoken to my code, VS Code says the code is fine, but the compiler fails

Can you help me why? Thanks!

Heres a part of my code:

```
      this.http
        .post<any>(`http://localhost:3000/api/login`, {
          username: data.username,
          password: data.password,
          token: token,
        })
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.logError = response.error;

          if (response.error == '') {

            let jwtsecKey= "my key. I deleted that"

            console.log(response);
            console.log(jwt.sign(response, jwtsecKey))
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

**Compiler:**

```
./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js:8:13-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\almak\Desktop\Chatenium\Chatenium\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }



× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: what does compiler say ?

Comment: Oh sorry, i will update the question

Comment: did you run npm ci/npm install ? because it can not find the module

Comment: yeah, i runned it again. still not working

Comment: did you try the suggestion that you see in your error message ? "install 'stream-browserify'" OR the alternative

Comment: yes, i tried adding fallback to polyfill and everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jsonwebtoken` is a Node.js module, its use in previous versions webpack relied upon a polyfill of the Node.js built-in modules. This most likely a) relied on slow js cryptography that isn't [maintained anymore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify) and lacks feature parity with Node's crypto and b) increased your js bundle size considerably. Webpack 5 no longer defaults to using these questionable crypto polyfill.

It is better to rely on JWT modules made to be consumed in browser environments, you can discover such modules on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/libraries?language=JavaScript) under "JavaScript" libraries.